# Разнообразие if

Tags: php

Сегодня насмотрелся на чужой код с большим количеством ифов. Все примерно одного содержания:

```
if(!$flag)  
if($flag == FALSE)  
if(FALSE == $flag)  
if($flag === FALSE)
```

Вопрос: какие есть положительные стороны в таком разнообразии? **Если они есть.**

**UPD:** могут ли быть проблемы с приведением типов? Например если в переменой файловый дескриптор?

Comment: Положительных сторон нет - только увеличение локальной энтропии и числа вариантов записать выражение с одной и той же семантикой. Я, правда, не уверен точно - возможно, существуют языки, в которых `if(!$flag)` не эквивалентно `if($flag == FALSE)`

Comment: если $flag - не булевый, а FALSE - это какая-то строка... и язык не php... тогда может быть всякое.

Comment: Если пишется код в команде, лучше, конечно, соблюдать какое-то единообразие. А приведенный пример - сплошное безобразие. 

Единственное замечание. Это, я так понимаю, PHP? Я его не знаю, поэтому прошу знающих объяснить, есть ли разница между операторами === и ==  ?

Comment: @KoVadim Да, вообще даже в том же самом `C++` можно с помощью оверлоада `operator bool` добиться неожиданного поведения от конструкции `!flag` - как-то вылетело из головы.

Comment: @mikillskegg, разница в том, что первый еще и типы сравнивает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это PHP, то сравнение `==` и `===` отличаются очень сильно. Вторая сравнивает еще и тип переменной, т.е.:

```
$a = '5';
$b = 5;
if ($a == $b)  echo 'выполнится';
if ($a === $b) echo 'не выполнится';
```

Код `if (!$flag)`, как минимум в PHP, можно рассматривать как короткую версию `if ($flag == FALSE)`.

Разница между `if ($flag == FALSE)` и `if (FALSE == $flag)` только в том, как вам удобнее или какого стандарта придерживаетесь. Мне логичнее проверять, что 'флаг не выставлен', чем 'не выставлен флаг'.
Стандарт кодирования Kohana, например, не рекомендует использовать второй вариант.

Answer (score 1):

1. Как правильно заметили, есть языки с отдельным булевским типом, а есть без отдельного. При этом последние тоже могут отличаться возможностью автоприведения типа. Например, в Си можно написать if (a), если a - целое, а в Паскале такой фокус не пройдет.
2. Идут очень жаркие дебаты как писать a==15 или 15==a. Вместо 15 можно подставить любое константное выражение, вместо a - любую переменную. Дело в том, что очень легко опечататься и поставить вместо оператора сравнения на равенство == оператор присвоения =. В случае выражения a=15 старое значение переменной перепишется на 15, а в случае 15=a компилятор сигнализирует об ошибке, что значение константного выражения нельзя изменить. Данная проблема характерна для Си-подобных языков. В том же Паскаде так ошибиться сложно.

В остальном могу предположить, что речь идет о php, и по его специфике товарищи ответили

Comment: Зато в Бейсике красота. Там не ошибешься

Comment: Не спец по бейсику, но там что?

Comment: А там оператор = используется и для присвоения, и для сравнения. Смотря по контексту.

Answer (score 0):

Разница между

```
if ($flag == FALSE) и if (FALSE == $flag)
```

скорее в том, что во втором случае, если вы случайно промахнетесь и поставите ОДИН знак равенства, вам система тут же сообщит об этом, так как FALSE - константа. 
В первом случае у вас всегда будет выдаваться ложное. Логические ошибки искать непросто.

А еще есть нормальное применение

```
if($a=$b)
```

Только оно скорее встречается в виде

```
if($a=func($b))
```

Comment: по моему опыту, ошибки вида `if ($flag = FALSE)` наблюдаются либо у самых начинающих (у них и других ошибок куча), либо у "хитрых специалистов", которые думают, что они оптимизировали.
Поэтому - "константа впереди" - это только для издевательства.

Comment: Сколько же начинающих тогда вокруг О_о

Comment: очень много. Ещё большая группа хорошо шифруется.